# how to set the ul li as active in css with angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

i want to set the ul li anchor tag as set active with angularjs.

this is my sidebar code

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">

    <li class="">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-desktop"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">
                Main Menu
            </span>
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
        </a>
        <b class="arrow"></b>
        <ul class="submenu">

            <li class="" id="RoleID">
                <a href="Role.html">
                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Role
                </a>
                <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
            <li class="" id="UserID">
                <a href="user.html">
                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    User
                </a>
                <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
            <li class="" id="countryID">
                <a href="country.html">
                    <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    Country
                </a>
                <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using master page from different header, footer, sidebar.html page.

all the html pages are shown in a "master.hmtl" page by using ng-include command.

here what my doubt is how to set active for "ul"under the  "li" anchor tag automatically when the page load.

this code is used to shown the sidebar in my masterpage.

```
<div class="main-container ace-save-state" id="main-container">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            debugger;
            try { ace.settings.loadState('main-container') } catch (e) { }
        </script>
        <div ng-include src="'sidebar.html'" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                try { ace.settings.loadState('sidebar') } catch (e) { }
                $(function () {
                    // init plugin (with callback)
                    $('#NameID').clearSearch({ callback: function () { console.log("cleared"); } });
                    $('#MUDescriptionID').clearSearch({ callback: function () { console.log("cleared"); } });
                                });
            </script>
        </div>

        <!-- /.main-content -->

    </div>
```

before i am not using ng-include method that time i am using this code to active the "li" automatically.

```
<script> $(function () {
                        $("#sidebar").load("slidebar.html", function () {
                $(".sidebar ul li ul li").closest("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
                $("#ManageUnitID").addClass("active").parents(".nav li").addClass("active open");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to dynamically add active class via the controller

Comment: Try to use event.currentTarget. If you need example I post it for you.

Comment: Hi  Volodymyr Kozlov, can you post the example

Comment: Hi  hunzaboy: can you post the example

Comment: @Vinoth did it work ?

Comment: :@Groben it is not working

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use angular. In your controller:

```
$scope.roles = [
    {
        id: 'RoleID',
        name: 'Role',
        href: 'Role.html',
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 'UserID',
        name: 'User',
        href: 'user.html',
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 'countryID',
        name: 'Country',
        href: 'country.html',
        active: false
    },
];
```

And instead of:

```
<li class="" id="RoleID">
    <a href="Role.html">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        Role
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>
<li class="" id="UserID">
    <a href="user.html">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        User
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>
<li class="" id="countryID">
    <a href="country.html">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        Country
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>
```

Just write this:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': role.active}" ng-repeat="role in roles" id="{{role.id}}">
    <a href="{{role.href}}">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        {{role.name}}
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>
```

And it will be really easy to set the class active on the element you want, e.g.:

```
$scope.roles[0].active = true;
```

You can also use a map:

```
$scope.roles =   {
   'RoleID': {
        name: 'Role',
        href: 'Role.html',
        active: false
   },
   'UserID': {
        name: 'User',
        href: 'user.html',
        active: false
   },
   'countryID': {
        name: 'Country',
        href: 'country.html',
        active: false
   }
}
```

And:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': role.active}" ng-repeat="(key, role) in roles" id="{{key}}">
    <a href="{{role.href}}">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        {{role.name}}
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>
```

So setting the value would be:

```
$scope.roles['RoleID'].active = true;
```

Comment: you need to tell me more, what about your controller ?